# Monomorphisms and epimorphisms in the category of Boolean algebras

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

A Boolean algebra is a ring with unity all of whose elements are idempotent.
We regard a zero ring $0$ as a Boolean algebra.
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the category of Boolean algebras.
A morphism in $\mathcal{B}$ is a homomorphism of rings preserving unity.
Is a monomorphism in $\mathcal{B}$ always injective?
Is an epimorphism in $\mathcal{B}$ always surjective?

Comment: Monomorphisms are always injective, because the forgetful functor $\mathcal{B} \to \mathbf{Set}$ has a left adjoint.

Answer (score 4):

In any algebraic category monomorphisms are injective, because the forgetful functor to the category of sets has a left adjoint (the free algebra on a given set) and therefore preserves monomorphisms. In the case of boolean rings, the free boolean ring on one generator is $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-x) \cong \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$, and hence the free boolean ring on a set $B$ is $\bigotimes_{b \in B} \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-x)$, where this is the (possibly infinite) tensor product as $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras, which is here also the coproduct in the category of boolean rings.

I don't know right now if epimorphisms are surjective, but using Stone duality this is equivalent to a pure topological question: If $A$ is a closed subspace of a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space $X$, does every open-closed subset of $A$ lift to a open-closed subset of $X$? If I remember correctly, there are (exotic) counterexamples.

Comment: Hans's answer implies it, but there is a direct argument that clopen subsets of closed subspaces extend to clopen subsets of the entire space in totally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $Q$ be your relatively clopen subset of $A$. Find an open set $U$ such that $A\cap U = Q$. Cover $A$ with clopen sets contained in $U$ (which exist since $X$ is totally disconnected) and find a finite subcover (which you can because $A$ is compact). Take the union of that cover.

Answer (score 4):

In the category of Boolean algebras, epimorphisms are surjective.  See B. Banaschewski, "On the strong amalgamation of Boolean algebras," Algebra universalis 63, pp. 235-238 (2010)